# To interact to/with each other

Tags: verbs, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

> I want to describe how objects interact **[to or with]** each other.

Which preposition should I use here to show how these objects interact?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: I found both wariants are acceptable and the dictionary still doesn't answer if it "good said" or whatever

Comment: Please include your research in the question and explain what is difficult to understand.

Comment: @AnnaBoten Where did you find that both variants are acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- interaction between sb and sb There's not enough interaction between
  the management and the workers.
- interaction of sth and sth A great advertising campaign comes from
  the successful interaction of strategic planning and creative skills.
- interaction with sb We select employees who will be good at
  face-to-face interaction with customers.
- interaction among sth The engineering conference encourages
  interactions among experts in different fields.

And in your case it's certainly right to say: Interact with each other

- These particles would give off no light and would interact with each
  other only slightly, through the weak nuclear force the same force
  that governs, for example , ...
- These particles would give off no light and would interact with each
  other only ... In either of these mirror worlds, particles would
  interact with each other by mirror  ...
- How Sound Waves Interact with Each Other. When different waves
  collide (e.g. sound from different sources) they interfere with each
  other. This is called ...
- do control to some degree how we interact with each other as two
  nations. ... interconnected individuals that interact with each other
  for mutual assistance or [.. .].

In rare cases I remember coming across "interact each other" instead of "interact with each other".

Comment: This would be a good answer if it were supported by _authoritative_ examples. Though 'In rare cases I remember coming across "interact each other" instead of "interact with each other".' is probably repeating error.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth http://pubget.com/articles/elasticsearch_show/18a37624-68e9-4ac5-ad42-4d9cf67506e8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038864/how-the-basicobject-object-and-kernel-interact-each-other All I can say from what I know, this is a common mistake.